# Can I create UI outside main thread (UI Thread)?

Tags: android, user-interface, view

my UI is pretty long to generate (about 20 seconds) for good reasons (calculating measurements of hundreds of views).
I (think?) have to create them in the main thread, and then I run a progressdialog to make the user wait.
Though, the main thread is  already overloaded by the creation of the other calculations.
Could I then create UI outside the main thread though I have to get measurements of several views?

Comment: I think you do something wrong if you really have hunderds of views. You may want to use a ListView.

Comment: "my UI is pretty long to generate (about 20 seconds) for good reasons (calculating measurements of hundreds of views)" -- "calculating measurements of hundreds of views" should take a few milliseconds. Beyond the repeated recommendations of not having "hundreds of views" in the first place, use Traceview to figure out why it is taking you this long.

Answer (score 2):

While some people say that they have got it to work, both [Dianne and Romain say](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/e-Rz0qMy0K8) that you should not do this in a discussion, as the entire UI tree is single threaded. They say that it is not guaranteed to work, and should be avoided.

I can't come up with any scenario in which you'd need hundreds of Views instantiated and drawn at the same time. Perhaps you need to use a ListView, or implement some kind of lazy loading in your app.