# Best practice for defining width & height for Android UI elements

Tags: android, xml, layout, width, resolution

I read in some posts that it's better to define ui elements in xml and not programmatically, and also that I should use dp units inside xml, so I wonder now how can I determine which **fixed** values should I use ?

Let's say I want to have an ImageView with a width that is 1/3 of the screen's width. Is there an **offline** way to find the dp number I should specify inside the xml or should I still set the height & width programmatically ?

Comment: Could you please provide a link to those posts about defining them in XML file is better?

Comment: As for your question, you need a DOM parser for that, I recommend DOMDocument.

Comment: it is not true, what can be done in xml can be done in Java *2.. all those linearLayout weights and stuff are not possible without java, so to your question, yes you need to do it the java way, use getMeasuredWidth() and divide it by 3

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827819/best-practices-layouts-on-android-programmatic-vs-xml

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29532974/could-there-be-any-performance-difference-between-writing-the-same-code-for-the

Comment: I know it's possible to do using code, but found these posts that suggested to use xml... Not sure why need DOM parser..